# ¿Cómo comparo la distribución de una variable en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo que comparar la distribución de las variables: edad, ingresos y población de una base de datos. También tengo que incluir gráficos.

¿Podríais decirme qué comandos puedo usar para esto? Tengo que hacerlo en R Studio.

Comment: El lenguaje es [r]. No olvides mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Los descriptivos básicos `mean(), var,() sd()` y para graficar puedes usar `plot()`

Comment: Y de paso, bienvenido Jose47 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.